# Django --- how to get pdf model upfront in a html download button?

Tags: django

I would like to create a HTML button where it loads the pdf file from the database. Do you know how to create the button to upload the latest pdf file from the model?

Below is my code so far from the model:

```py
class PdfLoad(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='Portfolios/')
```

Code for admin.py:

```py
admin.site.register(PdfLoad)
```

Code HTML code:

```html
        <!-- Download link -->
        <section class="about section" id="CV">
                <h2 class="section-title">Curriculum Vitae</h2>
                 <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                     <a href ="{{pdf.file}}"><button type="submit" class="cv__button"  onclick="blank">CV</button></a>
                        </div>
            </section>
```

do I have to do something for the setting.py file ??

Answer (score 0):

The file should have a url attribute with it.  This should allow you to access it:

```html
        <!-- Download link -->
        <section class="about section" id="CV">
                <h2 class="section-title">Curriculum Vitae</h2>
                 <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                     <a href ="{{ pdf.file.url }}"><button type="submit" class="cv__button"  onclick="blank">CV</button></a>
                 </div>
        </section>
```

Yes, you do have to add information to your settings.py:

```py
# settings.py 

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

You can change the `media` to the path of the folder where you have your pdf files stored, I guess it would be `Portfolios` in your case.  And I *think* the upload to should be `file = models.FileField(upload_to='/Portfolios')`.

Then add the following line to your context_processors:

```py
settings.py

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'django.template.context_processors.media', # ADD THIS LINE
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Changing media to the path of the folder where your pdf files are stored.

Comment: it seems to just load the page :)  when i click the button

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know if this works.